# Unable to create tensor

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, training-data, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to train an NLP model for MLM problem, but the trainer.train function is throwing:

> Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate truncation
> and/or padding with 'padding=True' 'truncation=True' to have batched
> tensors with the same length. Perhaps your features (`input_ids` in
> this case) have excessive nesting (inputs type `list` where type `int`
> is expected).

I really don't know what's going on because I followed the hugging-face tutorials.

Code:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer,AutoModelForMaskedLM
cp= "tau/tavbert-he"
model=AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(cp)
tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(cp)

import datasets
ds=datasets.load_dataset("csv", data_files='/content/drive/Shareddrives/Embible/data.csv')
ds=ds['train'].train_test_split(train_size=0.8, seed=42)


def tokenize_function(dataset):
  return tokenizer(str(dataset["verse"]),truncation=True,padding=True ,
                       max_length=512, return_overflowing_tokens=True)

tokenized_ds=ds.map(tokenize_function)

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm_probability=0.15)
tokenized_ds=tokenized_ds.remove_columns(ds["train"].column_names)

from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer


training_args = TrainingArguments("test-trainer")
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_ds['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_ds["test"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)
trainer.train()
```

Comment: What version of transformers do you use? Also if your code is based on a tutorial please provide the link.

Comment: the last version of transformers